# Xtrareport DevExpress Keep Table together with the first record

Tags: wpf, devexpress, xtrareport

I have some data that I want to be displayed the following way and I cannot find how to do it:

For example this would be the keep together case:
[image]

But I don't like that I have a lot of blank spaces when data is too much, so I would like the following to happen if possible. 
When the colNames and the first row can fit in the remaining space put them there.

[image]

Or if more can fit after the first row, put all of them there and split where it is possible if necessary.

[image]

Basically I want a 'Keep together' option for the columns and first row, and everything else can be splitted at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to achieve the same functionality do the following:

1. Put the table column names inside a `GroupHeader` and set its `GroupUnion` property to `WithFirstDetail`.
2. Put the table rows in the Detail next to the GroupHeader.

By doing this the `WithFirstDetail` property, as the name suggests, will try to keep the header with the first record, or move to the next page. Therefore achieving the behavior described above.